# R: load warnings

Tags: r, serialization, character-encoding

I have a file `foo`, which based on `file` utility is:

```
foo: LaTeX 2e document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

I have the following meta-code

```
txt <- readLines("foo")
....
save(txt, file="bar")
load("bar")
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In load("bar") :
  input string '...' cannot be translated to UTF-8, is it valid in 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'?
2: ...
```

The warnings cause some parts of the `txt` character vector to be cut when I later save it with `writeLines`
I was unable to find an explanations for the warnings. The warnings occur for lines in the TeX file with accented letters

Comment: When you do `readLines("foo")`, have you tried `readLines("foo", encoding = 'UTF-8")`?

Comment: @AllanCameron: please, see my answer with reproducible scripts

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, R reacts to the value of the `LANG` environment variable. If it is not set to an UTF-8 locale, R is unable to manage this type of encoding.

So if, calling R like so (no UTF-8):

```
LANG=en_US R
```

the console gives:

```
a <- rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xc3, 0xa0)))
a
# [1] "\303\240"
tmp <- file("/tmp/foo", encoding="UTF-8")        
writeLines(a, tmp)
# Warning message:
# In writeLines(a, tmp) : invalid char string in output conversion
close(tmp)
readLines("/tmp/foo")
# character(0)
```

Without an UTF-8 locale, the value of `a` (an accented a) is printed as raw bytes.
Forcing  UTF-8 encoding when writing to a file gives a warning and nothing is printed.

Calling with:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 R
```

does not give errors:

```
a <- rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xc3, 0xa0)))
a
# [1] "à"
tmp <- file("/tmp/foo", encoding="UTF-8")        
writeLines(a, tmp)
close(tmp)
readLines("/tmp/foo")
# [1] "à"
```

The problem here is that it is difficult to create portable scripts, because their results depends on the environment variables.

In Windows, R does not react to the `LANG` variable and the encoding depends on the language of Windows installed. For Latin languages this is ANSI. That makes simple the portability inside Windows, but R does not read properly Linux data files, based on UTF-8.

Comment: I've had the same issue, and changing language was not working. Turns out that the locale for the package is set at package build time. So I needed to set locale and build the package to solve the issue.